# Decorators are not valid here, Angular component constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to create a dialog component in Angular 17 using Angular material 17

Inside the dialog components constructor, I am unable to use @Inject decorator like the example provided in the official documentation

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reject',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MaterialModule],
  templateUrl: './reject.component.html',
  styleUrl: './reject.component.scss',
})
export class RejectComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, //Decorators are not valid here.ts(1206)
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RejectComponent>,
  ) {}

  public editorConfig = EDITOR_CONFIG;

  commentFormControl = new FormControl('');

  onCancel(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"],
    "paths": {},
    "rootDir": "."
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

Angular version: 17.0.7
Material version: 17.0.4
TypeScript version: 5.2.2

[image]

Comment: Do you have `import { Inject } from '@angular/core';` in your ts file?

Comment: @N.F - I have imported the Inject from angular core, I am still facing the issue, the issue is not cause because Inject unrecognised but it is because TS is not allowing annotation within constructor which is very strange behaviour

Comment: In your image is related to MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, check how provide microsoft-authentication in the [docs](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/configuration.md). Sorry, I've never use this library and I don't know about it.

Comment: Configuration is correct, please refer this [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-angular-v3-samples/angular16-sample-app/src/app/app.component.ts)